# How to get WPF ContentControl content to stretch?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm using a `ContentControl` to render various `UserControl` derivations dynamically.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the content to stretch when I resize the parent `Window`.  I've found many references like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767613/wpf-usercontrol-is-not-filling-parent-container-when-bound-at-runtime), but it's still not working for me.  Here is a simple example:

This is the `Window` XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        Content="{Binding Path=ChildView}" 
                        Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This uses the resource file `Dictionary1.XAML`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:viewModels ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
                    xmlns:views ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3">

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:UserControlViewModel}">
        <views:UserControl1/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here is the code behind for the main `Window` as well as the view model classes:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}    

public class MainViewModel
{
    public UserControlViewModel ChildView { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ChildView = new UserControlViewModel();
    }
}

public class UserControlViewModel
{

}
```

and finally the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Background="Blue" 
             Height="141" Width="278" 
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here's what it looks like at run time:

[image]
[image]

What am I missing here?  How can I get the child content to behave such that it remains anchored to the top/left of the parent and the bottom/right stretches as the parent is resized?

Comment: in what way doesnt it stay anchored to top/left if you use vertical and horizontal alignment `Stretch` on the contentcontrol?

Comment: @Dominik -- It doesn't.  It remains centered instead of anchored to the top/left.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Two things:

First, you want to remove the `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` on your `ContentControl`. Setting these will prevent the content control from stretching within its container, so `Width` and `Height` are respected, which are both zero by default (so the container has no size on its own).

Setting `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch`, or leaving it out since it’s the default, will make the container fill the grid, which is what you want.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=ChildView}" Margin="10" />
```

Second, setting `Width` and `Height` within the `UserControl` will set its size to that fixed size, so it will not adjust itself. Remove those attributes and the user control will default to stretch too, making it fill the content control.

If you want to have a certain size for design purposes, then set the *design size* instead of the actual control size. For that, you have the `d` XAML namespace which contains `DesignWidth` and `DesignHeight` properties. Setting these will affect the designer but they are ignored later when the view is rendered.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignWidth="400" d:DesignHeight="250"
        Background="Blue">
    …
</UserControl>
```

Comment: thank you so much i was struggling with this issue for a day

Answer (score 6):

You set the `Height` and `Width` property of the UserControl. This removes any leeway the WPF layouting has. So it does the best thing it can, which is centering the UserControl. If you remove the width and height, it should stretch as you expect.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Background="Blue" 
         Height="141" Width="278" //<-- remove 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As poke kindly reminded me, you also have to remove `VerticalAlignment="Top"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`

```
<ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Top" //<--remove
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"  //<--remove
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    Content="{Binding Path=ChildView}" 
                    Margin="10"/>
```

Comment: That alone won’t help, as the content control itself has no size.